# Visual studio is marking the debug folder as read only

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a c++ visual studio 2017 project, and every time I compile in debug mode the debug folder is marked as read-only. This force me to manually delete the debug folder in order to be able to recompile the project.

The project itself has a copy command in the post-build events to copy the .dll dependencies. This fails because of the read only setting that is changed automatically.

At the visual studio I have at home this is not happening and I have no clue of what is going on.